# How to edit "skin" instead of edit bones?

Tags: objects, armature, selection-tools

I am new to Blender. I downloaded a blender file with 2 rigged arms. I want to edit the shape of the arms, but when I press A or right click to select, I can only select the bones instead of the "skin" of the model. So what can I do?

Comment: Select the model in outliner, they probably overlap and blender doesn't know which one to select.. Or use Alt - click to select overlaping with menu

Comment: It is likely that the selection for the object is disabled. Go to the outliner and see if the mouse pointer icon is greyed out. If it is click on it to enable selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be because their selection has been limited in the outliner. To make sure this isn't the case, check and see if all of the pointer icons in the outliner are white, and not grey. Click them to change if they are.

[image]

This could also be if you are in the wrong mode. Armatures have three modes;

- [image] *Object mode* is portrayed by an orange cube, it allows you to change which object you can select
- [image] *Edit mode* is portrayed by a grey cube with four orange studs on its front (I suspect this is the one you're in) it only allows you to change the shape of the bones in your armature
- [image] *Pose mode* is portrayed by a small white man waving his hands around like he's trying to slow down a Taxi, it allows you to wiggle the bones around once they have been shaped right in edit mode.

You need to switch to **object** mode in order to select the mesh "skin" of your object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I need to be in object mode to select the mesh, so I was using edit mode :P

Comment: Cool. so now if you want to edit the mesh you have to have it selected and then switch into edit.---glad I could help.